# Laravel action when form validation generates error

Tags: laravel

I am working with a form request file like this:
`ProjectCreateRequest.php`

```
public function rules()
  {
    $project_name = $this->project_name;
    $meta_activity = $this->meta_activity;
    return [
      'project_name' => 'required|max:255|unique:projects',
      'customer_name' => 'required|max:255',
      'otl_project_code' => 'sometimes|max:255|unique:projects,otl_project_code,NULL,id,meta_activity,'.$meta_activity,
      'estimated_start_date' => 'date',
      'estimated_end_date' => 'date',
      'LoE_onshore' => 'numeric',
      'LoE_nearshore' => 'numeric',
      'LoE_offshore' => 'numeric',
      'LoE_contractor' => 'numeric',
      'revenue' => 'numeric',
      'win_ratio' => 'integer'
    ];
  }
```

There is the `otl_project_code` that must be unique with the meta_activity.

In case someone enters a pair of `otl_project_code` and `meta_activity` that already exists, it goes back to the create page with the error written below.

I would like to get instead that in the controller, I can catch this information, do something on the database then redirect to an update url.

Because I am working with a form validation request file, everything is entered in my controller like this:

```
public function postFormCreate(ProjectCreateRequest $request)
```

and I don't know how to catch this specific error in my controller to execute some actions with all the fields I submitted and not go back to the create page. Of course, this needs to happen only when there is the specific error I mentionned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the FormRequest response function in your ProjectCreateRequest:

```
/**
 * Get the proper failed validation response for the request.
 *
 * @param  array  $errors
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function response(array $errors)
{
    if ($this->expectsJson()) {
        return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
    }

    return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                                    ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
                                    ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
}
```

That's the public response on the FormRequest class so you can write your own logic to perform DB queries and redirect where needed.